# mpg321 playing too fast, at high pitch, via USB Audio

Tags: raspberry-pi, mp3, usb-audio

I'm trying to play an mp3 file on a Raspberry PI via USB Audio (iLuv Compact Speakers) and mpg321.

For some reason, it's playing the audio just a little bit too fast, and at a higher pitch than it should be.

If I play the audio through the headphone jack of the Raspberry PI instead, it plays the audio regularly.

How can I get it to play audio as it should sound through USB Audio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1: Use madplay to play the mp3 instead (sudo apt-get install madplay)

In this case, it seems my USB Audio would only play audio at 48KHz, whereas the mp3s I was trying to play were actually at 44.1KHz

It seems that mpg321 would try to play the audio at 44.1KHz anyways even though my USB Audio didn't support it, so it ended up playing it about 10% too quickly, and consequently at a higher pitch.

madplay seems to handle this scenario appropriately, and plays the audio as you'd expect to hear it.

EDIT:

Option 2: @derobert also has a solution in a comment below for how to get mpg321 to work properly in this scenario:

> "You could also try using the `plughw` device instead of `hw`, e.g., `mpg321 -o alsa -a plughw:0,0 …`. That should get ALSA to insert a sample-rate converter."

I still prefer Option 1 since it's simpler to write, but nice to know how to get mpg321 to work as well if you need it!

Comment: You could also try using the `plughw` device instead of `hw`, e.g., `mpg321 -o alsa -a plughw:0,0 …`. That should get ALSA to insert a sample-rate converter.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that when I get back. Definitely favor the ability to just call "madplay audio.mp3" and letting it handle it all for me, but interesting to know how to get mpg321 to work as expected.

Comment: Yup, confirmed that @derobert 's suggestion did make mpg321 play correctly!

Comment: now you can edit my suggestion into your answer ☺